# Почему React Yandex Maps зависает

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, nextjs, яндекс-карты

В Next.js я испоьзую библиотеку @pbe/react-yandex-maps. И время от времени карта зависает с ощибкой.

Код выглядит следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ощибка в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2582)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2549)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
    at Object._getPosition (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375:2620)
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_getPosition @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
findAfterValue @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1375
_addToGrid @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:39
_onGridBoundsMove @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:39
_onGridBoundsChange @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:39
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
fireChangeEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:38
_onMapMove @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:63
(анонимная) @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:63
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
_onActionChange @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:618
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
_applyBounds @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:594
_onActionEnd @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:594
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
end @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:591
end @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:593
release @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:4
_stopInertia @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:7
_onDragStart @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:7
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
_fireEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427
_onMouseMove @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
_onMouseEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:144

Uncaught Error: map.action.Continuous: ticking while inactive. browser:Chrome behavior:drag
    at o.tick (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:593:378)
    at o.tick (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:4:634)
    at o._onDragMove (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:7:3167)
    at s._callListeners (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:2983)
    at s.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:1002)
    at s.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149:694)
    at Object._fireEvent (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427:3157)
    at Object._onMouseMove (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427:1806)
    at s._callListeners (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:2983)
    at s.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:1002)
tick @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:593
tick @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:4
_onDragMove @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:7
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
_fireEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427
_onMouseMove @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:1427
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
_onMouseEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:144

Uncaught Error: map.action.Continuous: ticking while inactive. browser:Chrome behavior:scrollZoom
    at o.tick (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:593:378)
    at o.tick (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:4:634)
    at o._tick (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:24:3274)
    at o._onWheel (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:24:2262)
    at r._callListeners (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:2983)
    at r.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148:1002)
    at r.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149:1103)
    at n.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:150:512)
    at s.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149:775)
    at s.fire (full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149:775)
tick @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:593
tick @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:4
_tick @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:24
_onWheel @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:24
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:150
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:149
_onDomEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:851
_callListeners @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
fire @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:148
_onMouseEvent @ full-70275b62ece2fd2ab62f973df06797d58e0c96b5.js:144
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается карта зависает когда передаются объекты с пустыми значениями для lat и long то есть пустые координаты или не правильные значения
https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/45397